# Compact Data into Master Blade [every time it loads]

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

I am planning to organise a Notifications long polling for navbar icon (like Facebook) and I think the best place is to call it on my master page (`master.blade.php`).

I also have a shared controller that controls if user logged in or not.

Where do I need to call the function to return for master page? On the shared controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used shared controller and `view::share('variable', $variable)` to send the data every time master page is called.